# Hotspot of onTouchListener does not move along the TranslationAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout

In the run-time, I added a new ImageView and attached a listener, like so:

```
image = new ImageView(someAppContext());
relativeLayout.addView(image, someLayoutParam);
// add onTouch listener to the image view:
image.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      makeToast("touched!");
      return false; // tried return true, makes no difference
    }
});
```

After that, I used TranslateAnimation with `setFillAfter(true)`, so the ImageView would stay in the new position. However, the onTouch() is triggered if I touch the OLD position of the ImageView, but NOT the new position where the image visually is. How do I make the touch-sensitive hotspot move along with the ImageView itself? I also tried to `invalidate()`, doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Instead of toast I just log Log.d(TAG, "touch") and both the image and text got the touch event and click event respectively.

Comment: You are right, they are both triggered. I focused on the wrong problem: it has something to do with animations.

Answer (score 1):

Animation does not actually move Views. Translation animation only adds an offset to its coordinates.

I think the best workaround is to clear all the animations, and update layout parameters in order to move the actual ImageView over to the destination of the animation.

You need to store the destination of your translation, say `dest_x, dest_y`, and after the animation is done, do:

```
    someLayoutParam.leftMargin = dest_x;
    someLayoutParam.topMargin = dest_y;
    yourImageView.clearAnimation(); // resets its position
    yourRelativeLayout.updateViewLayout(yourImageView, someLayoutParam);
```

In this way, the location of the image view does not change, but the actual view is moved, so the touchable area is moved, too.